# Is $(f_*A)\times B\to f_*(A\times f^*B)$ an iso in a elementary topos?

Tags: category-theory, sheaf-theory, topos-theory

One can easily show by adjunction-nonsense that if we are given toposes $\cal E,F$ and a geometric morphism $f\colon \cal E\to F$ then there exist canonical arrows
$$
\begin{gather}
(f_*A)\times B\to f_*(A\times f^*B)\\
f^*(A\times f_*B)\to (f^*A)\times B
\end{gather}
$$
Working in categories of sheaves (for example $\mathcal O_X$-modules, $X$ a variety) one can also give sufficient condition (=flatness of one of the sheaves involved) for these maps to be isomorphisms. Can these condition be generalized to the scenario of Grothendieck and/or elementary toposes?

I'm interested in this because it seems to me that when they are iso, then $f$ commutes with the exponential bifunctor:
$$f_*(B^A)\cong f_*(B)^{f_*(A)}$$
$$f^*(B^A)\cong f^*(B)^{f^*(A)}$$

Comment: It sounds like you are interested in [logical functors](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/logical+functor).

Comment: So are you saying that when $f$ is atomic, then $(f_*A)\times B\cong f_*(A\times f^*B)$ and
$f^*(A\times f_*B)\cong (f^*A)\times B$?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I do remember that logical functors are supposed to preserve the logical structure of an elementary topos, and I think the exponentials are part of the logical structure. I may be wrong.

Comment: What I think I'm able to prove according to the page of nlab is the following: "$f_*(B^A)\cong f_*(B)^{f_*(A)}$ iff $f_*$ is an equivalence of categories" Which I find quite astonishing!